# How to stop a session with a button?

Tags: php

I have a form and added a session_starts  I want to track of how many times I have visited the page ..I want a Button indicating the stop session and the session should stop and start with a new session ...How do I do this?

Comment: What have you got so far?

Answer (score 1):

Suggestion:
Try creating a button in a form and after submitting it change session values to what you want and the start another.

Example

```
<form method="POST">
<input type="submit" name="emptySession">
<form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['emptySession']){
//you continue
 }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd have thought that something like the following ought to work- the logic can be adapted to suit whatever page you have.

```
<?php

    session_start();

    if( !empty( $_POST['reset'] ){
        @session_unset();
        @session_destroy();
        @session_start();
        @session_regenerate_id( true );
    }

?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>Sessions</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method='post'>
            <input name='reset' value='Reset' type='submit' />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```